# Access denied error while modifying remote computer folder permission

Tags: powershell

Writing code to add the permission to specific folder in remote computer. Our code runs with system user hence in code we performed the user context switch from system to domain user & then execute the command from local computer to add domain user permission in remote computer folder. While executing the code getting an access denied error. Below is the code for your reference.

Code to change permission (test.ps1):

```
$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Read, Write" 
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None  
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 
$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domain\username") 
$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 
$objACL = Get-ACL "\\remote-computer\test" 
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 
Set-ACL "\\remote-computer\test" $objACL
```

Code to perform user context switch:

```
$username = "domain\username"
$password = "Password"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
$session= new-pssession -ComputerName $Env:ComputerName -Credential $credential
invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {whoami}
invoke-command -Session $session -FilePath C:\Users\Desktop\test.ps1
```

Error:

> Access is denied CategoryInfo: PermissionDenied: 
>   (\remote-computer\test:String) [Get-ChildItem],
>   UnauthorizedAccessException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>
> ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
>   + PSComputerName: local-computer

Comment: This looks like a double-hop problem because you are impersonating a different user then you are connecting to a share on yet another server - this isn't allowed.  Even though you are connecting to the same computer you are on, I think the fact you go 'out' then 'back in' via remoting, this counts as a hop.  If you log onto the 'admin' server as the user, can you then connect and manage the remote share?

Comment: Yes I am able to manage the remote share

Comment: Seem like it may be an impersonation issue then.  Two options to try are [enabling CredSSP](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting/), or [passing the credentials to your invoked script](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/935286-i-ve-found-a-way-to-side-step-double-hop-just-how-insecure-is-it), then impersonate again to go to the next hop.

Comment: does the user you try to use has necessary permissions on local machine [PSComputerName: local-computer] ?
you can try using 'run as other user'  just holsd shift and lick right on the powershell icon then input pwd and run just the ACL commands to see if you can do the things you want another thing is policy,probably the other user has no logon rights on this PC